Langchain Deno Import Map cannot use common langchain/core
Using Supabase Langchain Edge Functions, I cannot seem to force resolve the same langchain/core package version using import_map scopes.
I'm trying to import:
langchain/
@langchain/core
@langchain/groq 
@langchain/openai

But langchain/ @langchain/groq @langchain/openai all use different version of @langchain/core causing weird type mismatch issues like Type 'PromptTemplate<any, any>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Runnable<any, any, RunnableConfig>'.
For example this code does not compile:
    import { ChatGroq } from "@langchain/groq";
    import { ChatOpenAI } from "@langchain/openai";

    const openAi = new ChatOpenAI(...);    
    const groq = new ChatGroq(...);

    const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([...]);

    // TYPE MISMATCH ERROR 
    const wontCompileChain = prompt.pipe(openAi);
    const compilingChain = prompt.pipe(groq);

I've tried:
    {
  "imports": {
    "langchain/": "https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.12/",
    "@langchain/core/": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/",
    "@langchain/groq": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/groq@0.0.17/"
    "@langchain/openai": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/openai@0.3.0/",
  },
  "scopes": {



Override the import from esm.sh
"https://esm.sh/": {
  "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/"
},


Override import of langchain core used in langchain/ and @langchain/openai , note that groq already uses the same version. This just doesn't do anything to fix the type mismatch error:
"https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.27/": {
  "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
},
"https://esm.sh/@langchain/openai@0.3.0/": {
  "@langchain/core/": "https://esm.sh/v135/@langchain/core@0.2.29/"
}


Override the import using the same import path seen in the langchain files (I get error: error: Module not found "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/denonext/denonext/language_models/chat_models.js".) when resetting the deno cache:


   "https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.12/": {
      "https://esm.sh/v135/@langchain/core@0.2.31/": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/"
    },


I also tried overriding the langchain core imports to be 0.2.27 but still get the same type mismatch error suggesting that another version of langchain/core is still being used.

 
    "https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.27/": {
      "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
    },
    "https://esm.sh/@langchain/groq@0.2.27/": {
      "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
    },
    "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/": {
      "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
    },
    "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/": {
      "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
    },
    "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.31/": {
      "@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"

I've spent hours trying to resolve this. If you can, please help prove I'm a fool for missing some documentation because I'm pretty sure I've scoured the web for answers on this ... only just saw this:
https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/modules/

How are you importing these package.
are your using package.json.

Hey @PuneetSharma I use import maps, there is no package.json like normal projects

Can you provide an example of what your imports look like? Or what you’re trying to import, the referring module and the specifier used.

Hi @morganney that is provided above ie:
{
"imports": {
"langchain/": "https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.12/",
"@langchain/core/": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/",
"@langchain/groq": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/groq@0.0.17/"
},
"scopes": {
And in the section below I detail the different scopes I tried:
"https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.27/": {
"@langchain/core": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.27/"
},
And
"https://esm.sh/langchain@0.2.12/": {
"https://esm.sh/v135/@langchain/core@0.2.31/": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core@0.2.29/"
},

I’m not asking about your import maps I’m asking about the actual import statements in your code.

Like this:
import { ChatGroq } from "@langchain/groq";
import {
ChatPromptTemplate,
MessagesPlaceholder,
} from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import { RunnableWithMessageHistory } from "@langchain/core/runnables";
import { BaseListChatMessageHistory, InMemoryChatMessageHistory } from "@langchain/core/chat_history";

Ok, thanks. So now it would help if you provided sample code that produces the error. All you’ve shown are import maps.

import { ChatOpenAI } from "@langchain/openai";
import { ChatGroq } from "@langchain/groq";
import {
ChatPromptTemplate,
} from "@langchain/core/prompts";

Very simple case: (const openAi = new ChatOpenAI) (const groq = new ChatGroq)
and I cannot even call :  const chain = prompt.pipe(openAi);

Without getting:
Argument of type 'ChatOpenAI' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RunnableLike<ChatPromptValueInterface, AIMessageChunk>'.

Suggestion:
langchain-groq: 0.1.9
langchain-core: 0.2.35
This is current version. Ensure you use the same. Then see if it resolves. Also see if any warnings are there while running your app. Don't ignore them.
Long suggestion:
I ran into a similar issue with Llama index where langchain version is different. But could not find a solution to it. The best case is to reach out to groq support or langchain SLACK community and explain them.
This likely requires vendor side check if its a bug. Since these are evolving rapidly, there might be bugs.
So, with that I would recommend you to design your app in a different way to reduce any of the dependencies. Because vendor side fix is a long shot.
That said, create an issue in langchain GitHub.

The issue isn’t in only using langchain/core and groq but also langchain as well… langchain docs say you can force resolve a common version of langchain/core using overrides in package.json but that isn’t possible in deno import maps.. using their resolves is supposed to work but it doesn’t seem to in my case as described above

Here's and example that works for me without producing any type errors.
deno.json
{
  "tasks": {
    "dev": "deno run --watch main.ts"
  },
  "imports": {
    "@langchain/core": "npm:@langchain/core@^0.3.0",
    "@langchain/groq": "npm:@langchain/groq@^0.1.1"
  }
}

main.ts
import { ChatGroq } from "@langchain/groq";
import { ChatPromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";

const model = new ChatGroq({
  apiKey: <API-KEY>,
});
const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
  ["system", "You are a helpful assistant"],
  ["human", "{input}"],
]);
const chain = prompt.pipe(model);
const response = await chain.invoke({
  input: "Hello",
});

console.log("response", response.content);

You can try deno run main.ts and deno check -all main.ts.
Also works in HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Langchain</title>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@langchain/groq": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/groq",
        "@langchain/core/": "https://esm.sh/@langchain/core/"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { ChatGroq } from "@langchain/groq";
      import { ChatPromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";

      const model = new ChatGroq({
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
      });
      const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
        ["system", "You are a helpful assistant"],
        ["human", "{input}"],
      ]);
      const chain = prompt.pipe(model);
      const response = await chain.invoke({
        input: "Hello",
      });

      document.body.innerHTML = response.content;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


Thanks @morganney. However it looks like you've chosen the version of groq that uses the same version of core. The challenge is also to include other packages such as langchain/openai and langchain/ that also rely on core. They all end up using different versions of core and triggering the type errors.

I'd be happy to dig in further, but you need to add an actual example of how you are using these packages in your question. Not just the import maps but the actual code you are writing.

Much appreciated. Something as simple as:
const openAi = new ChatOpenAI(...);
const groq = new ChatGroq(...);
const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([...]);

// TYPE MISMATCH ERROR 
const wontCompileChain = prompt.pipe(openAi);
const compilingChain = prompt.pipe(groq);


I edited the original question since it's easier to display code there.

Ok. I am able to reproduce.
